# How to get user input from a prompt(terminated by press ENTER) in c++?

Tags: c++, console

Anyone knows this tip?

Answer (score 5):

Try `getline`:

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Return key is the easy case, as Mehrdad answered, just read something from `std::cin`.

If you want to terminate on a different key press, for example, exit on any key, you can use a couple non-standard calls in `conio.h`.

```
#include <conio.h>

// wait for any key press
while (!kbhit()) { }

// wait for q key press
while (!kbhit() || getch() != q) { }

// wait for any key press on windows
system("pause");
```