# get user input (terminate by enter key)

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

I use `scanf` to get user input but if I press enter, the cursor will flash to next line. What function should I use instead of `scanf` if I want the program to terminate if the users only press enter without keying anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538007/how-to-get-user-input-from-a-promptterminated-by-press-enter-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Scanf reads until the next *token* -- it doesn't really care about newlines at all (just considers them to be whitespace, like spaces or tabs).

Instead, use a line-reading function like [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: how to check the input to terminate the program if only press enter?

Comment: If you use `fgets`, you will only read one line no matter what (unless you put it in a loop). Therefore, if the user presses enter without typing anything, `fgets` will return an empty line. Therefore, if the line is empty, you can just terminate the program right away.

Comment: that's kinda intresting what you have said about scanf. what makes the function return?

Comment: @stupid_idiot `scanf` always reads a whole word (separated by spaces). You can think of it as simply using `getc` to read a single character (which means it waits for the user to type a line, then reads a character from that line) in a loop. It won't stop until it has seen a whole word. So if the user just keeps pressing enter, it just keeps waiting until it sees an actual word.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gets() function in this way :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_INPUT_CHAR 100
int main( ) {

   char str[MAX_INPUT_CHAR ];

   printf( "Enter a value :");
   gets( str );   

   return 0;
}
```

> Function  **char *gets(char *s)** reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to by
>   s until either a terminating newline or EOF (End of File)

Pay attention gets() is not safe. You can't now apriori how much character it will read. This can cause  some security problem and eventually crash.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this code :

```
char ch;
printf("Enter Your Sentence \n");
while (1) 
{ 
     ch = getch();
     if ((int)ch == 13) 
         break;
     printf("%c", ch);
}
```